# Twisted execute python file

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

Is there any way to get a twisted webserver to execute a python file like cgi on a conventional webserver? So, when i navigated to a directory, i could execute python within a seperate file?

I have created a basic webserver, but it only returns static content like text or HTML files:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.internet import reactor

resource = File('/root')
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

I understand why it may not be possible, but i couldn't find any documentation. Thanks

EDIT: I found a solution. Instead of going through the hassle of directories, i'm simply parsing GET requests and treating them like fake files. The CGI is executed within the main file.

THanks

Comment: Do you want actual CGI or do you just want easily scriptable resources written in Python, not conforming to any particular standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this example that might do what you want.

Take a look [Twisted Web Docs](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#adding-children) for some more info.  Search the page for CGI.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import static, server, twcgi

root = static.File("/root")
root.putChild("cgi-bin", twcgi.CGIDirectory("/var/www/cgi-bin"))
reactor.listenTCP(80, server.Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: This works, though it's probably not the best idea (you'd have to run it as root to bind to port 80 and on Linux, and a number of other Unix like systems, such as FreeBSD, you'd be serving up the */root/*  (the 'root' user's home) directory.

Comment: This worked for me. The import part of this solution is the root.putChild("cgi-bin", twcgi.CGIDirectory("/var/www/cgi-bin")) line.  The rest of it might need tweaking, and you might want to use alternate directory names / paths.The concept is spot on though.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @SonuMishra fixed the link

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use the Twisted WSGI server for that.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html

It doesn't exactly execute the Python file, but calls an "application". But that's better since it doesn't have to start a new Python process.

You can also use the twisted CGI support, which will execute the file, but using Twisted to run Python scripts with CGI is a bit like using a sports car as a tractor.